# import multi branch xml data into mysql table using "load xml infile"

Tags: mysql, xml

I'm trying to import multi branch xml file data into table but it's not inserting into the table.

Please find the xml image

[image]

and I want to insert into the following columns respectively

[image]

Please help me.

Thanks in advance

Comment: that's not what `load xml` is for. mysql's xml load support is basically a glorified CSV file, and isn't intended for "real" xml documents.

Comment: Is there any another way to load that xml data into mysql using native queries ?